# How to lock multiple locks where some are shared and some are not in C++

Tags: c++, concurrency, locking, mutex, deadlock

Let's suppose I have some threadsafe class. It uses a `std::shared_mutex` for protection against concurrent access. Read only operations use a `std::shared_lock`, while write operations use `std::scoped_lock`.

Now, in the case of the copy assignment operator both the assignee's and the object's being assigned mutexes must be locked, except that the assignee gets modified and must have its mutex locked with `std::shared_lock` while the object being assign is read-only and must be locked using `std::scoped_lock`. As far as I know, locking multiple mutexes without using a specific lock ordering algorithm, like this, could cause a deadlock.

Normally a deadlock could be circumvented by using `std::lock` or `std::scoped_lock`, but in this case, they cannot be used, as one of the `std::shared_mutex`es must not be `lock`ed, but `lock_shared`ed.

How can multiple locks be locked avoiding a deadlock, where some of them are shared and some are not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In very same way you should be using function `std::lock` for multiple mutexes.

Let me give you an example:

```
  std::mutex m;
  std::shared_mutex sm;
 
  std::unique_lock ul(m,std::defer_lock);
  std::shared_lock sl(sm,std::defer_lock);
  
  std::lock(ul,sl);
```

Function `std::lock` simply applies `try_lock()/unlock()` until it succedes on all input lockables whereas `shared_lock`'s methods `lock/try_lock` impose shared locking (for reading).

Comment: So simple. Somehow, I thought that locking a shared lock locks it in exclusive mode rather than in shared mode. I confused it with locking the shared mutex itself.

Answer (score 1):

Just fix your design so this doesn't happen. The issues with deadlock and difficulty of code maintenance are going to be intolerable with a design like this.

For example, maybe copy the source object to a temporary, unlock it, and then copy the temporary to the destination object. Or, alternatively, have a single lock that protects all the objects and architect so you don't hold it very long.

Comment: Copying to a temporary is certainly a solution, but what if the object is a container and is expensive to copy? Also why is this design difficult to maintain? It seems quite simple and straightforward.

Comment: @enthusiastic_3d_graphics_pr... It's difficult to maintain because what you can do when you hold particular locks varies due to the risk of deadlock.

Comment: What about using a copy+swap? It wouldn't require holding the two locks simultaneously and would make only a single copy if swap would move the objects' data.

Comment: Support for move semantics would probably work as well. You can them move from the copy, so you're only copying once.